# Export data to a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, xpath

I am scraping this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/netherlands/eerste-divisie-2018-2019/results/ I want to extract matches, results and date. I used this code:

```
    df=[]
    matches=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='in-match']")

    for match in range(len(matches)):
        df.append(matches[match].text)
        
    results=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='h-text-center']")
    
    for result in range(len(results)):
        df.append(results[result].text)
        
    date=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'h-text-right')]")
    
    for data in range(len(date)):
        df.append(date[data].text)


df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[['match', 'result', 'data']])
```

I want to export to a dataframe but I got this error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (24, 1), indices imply (24, 3)`

Comment: Did you try, [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe have only one column but in `columns=[['match', 'result', 'data']]` you passed three columns name which gives you an error.

```
   df=[[] for x in range(3)]

    matches=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='in-match']")

    for match in range(len(matches)):
        df[0].append(matches[match].text)
        
    results=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='h-text-center']")
    
    for result in range(len(results)):
        df[1].append(results[result].text)
        
    date=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'h-text-right')]")
    
    for data in range(len(date)):
        df[2].append(date[data].text)


data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
data_frame['match'] = df[0]
data_frame['result'] = df[1]
data_frame['data'] = df[2]
```

Comment: How could I split dataframe in three columns?